# Limits with squares

Tags: calculus, limits

I have problem with finding such limits:

a) $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^2}{7^{\sqrt{n}}}$

b) $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{3^{\sqrt{n}}}{2^n} $

I think the method of solving this two is similar but I don't know what tool to use. 
I tried using the fact that if $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_{n}|}<1$ then $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=0$ but it dosn't work

Answer (score 2):

Hint: try to prove that $n^3\le 7^{\sqrt n}$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Another hint: try to prove that $2^{n/2}\ge 3^{\sqrt n}$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Global hint: use logarithms.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for a) : An exponential function increases faster than any polynomial function.

Hint for b) : $3^{\sqrt n}=2^{\sqrt n \frac{log3}{log2}}$